# Matplotlib: Creating axes with fixes dimensions (e.g. in cm), so that axes do not change dimensions when resizing the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a figure with 2 sublots. I use the main one for showing data with one shared x-axis (performancewise that is better than having moltiple subplots). And the second one, the assist-axes I "missuse" for plotting the axis lables and ticks for the main one. (Later a teble should be added additionally)

I am searching a solution to fix the dimesions of the assist-axes. So that it stays the same size (esp. in horizontal directio) even when one change the size of the figure. The ,main plot of course should beginn at the same place and should stick to the border of the assist-axes.

Here are 2 pictures to show what I mean:

[image: Normal size with good readability of lables]

[image: Changed size with bad readability, because the assist-axes is compressed.]

What I tried:
Beginning with only one subplot, I found out that I can handle this single subplot with subplots_adjust, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

cm = 1/2.54
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7*cm, 7*cm))
width = fig.get_size_inches()[0] * 2.54
fig.add_subplot()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=4/width)


def on_size_change(*unused_events):
    width = fig.get_size_inches()[0]*2.54
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=4/width)


fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", on_size_change)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Normal fig size]

[image: Small fig size]

But of course, as long as I cannot (or at leat I do not know how) adjust subplots/axes wirh "subplots_adjust", that does not helf me for my problem.